# How to set a Drawable based on a filename programatically

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I have an Array of countries (Strings) - (Comes from a webservice) as well as a corresponding list of Drawables which are their flags - (In the drawables folder)

The Drawables are labelled "cape_verde" or "canada" but when the names come down from the webservice they come down as "Cape Verde" or "Canada".

When I call the webservice I do a lowercase conversion and replace some characters as seen in the code below:

```
String lowerCaseName = countryNameInArray.countryName.toLowerCase();
String replacedCountryName = lowerCaseName.replaceAll(" ", "_");
```

My thought was that I can some how set the

```
R.drawable.replacedCountryName
```

but obviously it cant take Strings as its requires an int.

**EDIT:**

```
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    countries = res.getStringArray(R.array.countries);

    /********** Inflate spinner_rows.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.country_drop_down_rows, parent, false);

    /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
    tempValues = null;
    tempValues = (countryDropDownItem) data.get(position);

    TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_country_textview);
    ImageView country = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_county_flag_imageview);



    if (position == 0) {

        // Default selected Spinner item
        label.setText("South Africa"); //get the country text
        country.setImageResource(R.drawable.south_africa);

    } else {
        String lowerCaseName = countries.toString().toLowerCase();
        String replacedCountryName = lowerCaseName.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        // Set values for spinner each row
        label.setText(tempValues.countryName); //get the country text
        country.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier(replacedCountryName, "drawable", "com.app.app" ));
    }

    return row;
}
```

Has anyone got an idea how I can go around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ImageView iw= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable",  getPackageName());
iw.setImageResource(resID);
```

drawableName is your file/image name, try to store in /src/asset/image.png

Comment: Thanks a mill, i have tried this but for some reason its not setting the image. I have added the code that i am using to the question as it is in my app... Its being used in a Spinner and its not setting the images, but the names are working fine

Answer (score 2):

```
getResources().getIdentifier(
            "imagename", "drawable", "com.package.application")
```

Comment: Thanks a mill, i have tried this but for some reason its not setting the image. I have added the code that i am using to the question as it is in my app... Its being used in a Spinner and its not setting the images, but the names are working fine